# Display distinct record in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

**APEX CONTROLLER:**

```
 productInvList = new list<ProductInventory__c> ();

        inv =[Select ProductID__r.Name,ProductID__r.Launch__c, ProductID__r.ProductID__c, ProductID__r.More_Colors__c, ProductID__r.Category__c,Image2__c, Image3__c, Image4__c, ProductID__r.Price__c, Colour__c, Size__c, Quantity__c,AllowBackorders__c FROM ProductInventory__c WHERE ProductID__r.Launch__c <= :myDateTime ORDER BY ProductID__r.Launch__c DESC ];

        Map<String, ProductInventory__c > mapStrByzip =new Map<String, ProductInventory__c >();

        for(ProductInventory__c zipone: inv){
            mapStrByzip.put(zipone.ProductID__r.Name ,zipone);//This is map and hence it will always have unique values                           
        }

        for (ProductInventory__c dd: mapStrByzip.values()){
              productInvList.add(dd);
        }
```

productInvList will be used to display on VF pageblocktable.

As shown, I'm trying to display productInvList. However, I'm not able to display the productInvList by ProductID__r.Launch__c DESC.

I've tried putting in below code after the for loop, it display according to the launch date DESC. But the same products are shown repeatedly. How do I go about fixing the issue? Thanks guys!

**APEX CONTROLLER:**

```
productInvList = [Select ProductID__r.Name,ProductID__r.Launch__c, ProductID__r.ProductID__c, ProductID__r.More_Colors__c, ProductID__r.Category__c,Image2__c, Image3__c, Image4__c, ProductID__r.Price__c, Colour__c, Size__c, Quantity__c,AllowBackorders__c 
                  FROM ProductInventory__c 
                  WHERE ProductID__r.Launch__c <= :myDateTime 
                  ORDER BY ProductID__r.Launch__c DESC 
                 ];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you wrote the following:

```
   for(ProductInventory__c zipone: inv){
      mapStrByzip.put(zipone.ProductID__r.Name ,zipone);
      //This is map and hence it will always have unique values                           
   }
```

The "value" part of the map is `zipone`. The key part of the map is `zipone.ProductID__r.Name`. Its the keys which will always be unique. Whenever a duplicate key is encountered, it will overwrite the value stored in the map for `zipone`.

If you want to assure that you have unique Ids, you could change your query to something like the following:

```
map<Id, ProductInventory__c>invMap = new map([Select ProductID__r.Name,ProductID__r.Launch__c, ProductID__r.ProductID__c, ProductID__r.More_Colors__c, ProductID__r.Category__c,Image2__c, Image3__c, Image4__c, ProductID__r.Price__c, Colour__c, Size__c, Quantity__c,AllowBackorders__c FROM ProductInventory__c WHERE ProductID__r.Launch__c <= :myDateTime ORDER BY ProductID__r.Launch__c DESC ]);

new set<Id>invId = invMap.keyset();
list<ProductInventory>inv = new list<ProductInventory>();

For(Id ProductInventoryId : invId){
   inv = invMap.get(ProductInventoryId);
}

// you now have a list where the Id's are unique

Map<String, ProductInventory__c > mapStrByzip =new Map<String, ProductInventory__c >();
```

Below you take the object name and map it to the object where you've declared the object as a string? I'm sorry, but I don't follow this and don't think you're on the right track here and have no idea what you're trying to do. Perhaps you need to do some casting or declare a wrapper class of some kind?

```
for(ProductInventory__c zipone: inv){
    mapStrByzip.put(zipone.ProductID__r.Name ,zipone);    
}

for (ProductInventory__c dd: mapStrByzip.values()){
    productInvList.add(dd);
}
```

**Edit:**

For your ProductID__r.Launch__c DESC, If the above is working for you, try something like this:

```
list<ProductInventory__c>productInvList = new list<ProductInventory__c>();

map<Id,ProductInventory__c>productInvMap = new map([Select ProductID__r.Name,ProductID__r.Launch__c, 
     ProductID__r.ProductID__c, ProductID__r.More_Colors__c, ProductID__r.Category__c,Image2__c, 
     Image3__c, Image4__c, ProductID__r.Price__c, Colour__c, Size__c, Quantity__c,AllowBackorders__c 
          FROM ProductInventory__c 
          WHERE ProductID__r.Launch__c <= :myDateTime 
              ORDER BY ProductID__r.Launch__c DESC]);

Set<Id>prodinvId = productInvMap.keyset();

For(Id ProdInventoryId : prodinvId){
   productInvList = productInvMap.get(ProdInventoryId);
}
```

You can always put the above into a map instead if you want to pass it to your page in that form. Since it's not at all clear to me what `zipone` is, I can't really help you further.

Comment: @crmprogdeb Thank you for your reply. The below code that you've put is for display on VF page. Basically im using productInvList to display on my VF pageblock.

Comment: Its always helpful to distinguish between apex controller code and VF code. People trying to help you have no way of knowing if you don't tell us when we see generic looking code like that. It would be helpful if you edit your post to distinguish what code is is apex and what's VF. Edit link is at bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set instead of List.
That should prevent repeating values.

Comment: I believe you're on the right track, but unfortunately your post lacks detail that leaves it very incomplete to make it a suitable answer to the question. For that reason, I have to agree with mastOr that your post does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow below steps to make sure uniqueu records are appearing in VF.

1. Use Set of [Wrapper class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) instead of List.
2. Implement [equals and Hashcode method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm) in your wrapper class, It will help Salesforce to identify unique records.

If you want to learn how exactly equals and hashcode method works, you can check [this article](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/what-is-the-need-to-override-hashcode-and-equals-method/) as well.